# Using numbers in a list to access items in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the items:

```
my_list = [18, 15, 22, 22, 25, 10, 7, 25, 2, 22, 14, 10, 27]
```

in a list and I would like to use these to access items inside my dictionary by using a 'for loop', I will then append these items to a new list. My dictionary looks like this:

```
my_dict = {1:"A", 2:"B", 3:"C" ... 26:"Z", 27:"_"}
```

How would I got about doing this? I have tried loops like this:

```
for i in my_list:
    my_newlist = []
    letters = number_value[keys.index(i)]
    letters.append(my_newlist)
```

However I am getting errors in doing so. Cheers.

In another area of my code I have the revers function, in which I get the key by searching for the item with:

```
for i in my_list:
    third_list = []
    num_val = keys[values.index(i)] + key_shift
    third_list.append(num_val)
    print(num_val)
```

It's being used in a substitution cypher code. The sample above works, it looks in the dictionary for the key which corresponds to "A" and stores the key in a list.

Comment: where are `number_value` and `keys` defined?

Comment: .. and why are you doing `key.index(i)`? What are you expecting to see in letter as a result?

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Fixed. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Today, I moved a solution merged into this question to an answer box, but that looks like it may be rejected in the review queue for being a link-only answer. It reads thus: "Encrypter is now working. You can find a version [here](https://github.com/Bluestormy/Python/blob/master/Python%20Encrypter.py)". OP, if you want to expand on this in an answer without a link, that may be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) where you implicitly loop through your list of numbers `my_list` and retrieve the value form your dict `my_dict` using the respective number as a key:

```
my_dict = {i: chr(i+64) for i in range(27)}
my_list = [1, 5, 19]

result = [my_dict[i] for i in my_list]
print(result)
```

yields

```
['A', 'E', 'S']
```

Make sure to check for `KeyError`, because your list `my_list` may contain numbers that are not present in your dict `my_dict`. If you want to avoid explicit exception handling (and silently omit missing keys), you can do something like this:

```
result = [my_dict[i] for i in my_list if i in my_dict.keys()]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code snipped does not seems to be complete because you are using the variable `number_values` which is not defined in your example. 
EDIT: You still are using variables which are not defined in the code snipped you provided so I cant reproduce your error. In addition you are overwriting your `third_list` and `my_newlis` every time

I assume that the keys in `my_list` are also present in `my_dict` : If not do as @jbndlr told you and check for `KeyError`.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 26, 27]

my_dict = {1:"A", 2:"B", 3:"C" , 26:"Z", 27:"_"}

my_newlist = []
for i in my_list:
    letters = my_dict[i]
    my_newlist.append(letters)

print my_newlist
```

This yield the the items. If you are looking for something else let me know so I can adjust the answer

Comment: Yeah, it is from extracts from a code I am working on. I had to simplify the variable names, as I have quite a few in my code for the cypher. When the code is finished, I'll upload it to my GitHub at https://github.com/Bluestormy/Python. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the inconsistencies in your code sample, so blithely ignoring those :)

```
my_list = [18, 15, 22, 22, 25, 10, 7, 25, 2, 22, 14, 10, 27]
my_dict = {0: '@', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E', 6: 'F', 7: 'G', 8: 'H', 9: 'I', 10: 'J', 11: 'K', 12: 'L', 13: 'M', 14: 'N', 15: 'O', 16: 'P', 17: 'Q', 18: 'R', 19: 'S', 20: 'T', 21: 'U', 22: 'V', 23: 'W', 24: 'X', 25: 'Y', 26: 'Z', 27: '_'}
my_newlist = []
for i in my_list:
    letters = my_dict[i]
    my_newlist.append(letters)

my_newlist
['R', 'O', 'V', 'V', 'Y', 'J', 'G', 'Y', 'B', 'V', 'N', 'J', '_']

#Now reverse the operation to build third_list

third_list = []
for i in my_newlist:
    key = my_dict.keys()[my_dict.values().index(i)]
    third_list.append(key)

third_list
[18, 15, 22, 22, 25, 10, 7, 25, 2, 22, 14, 10, 27]
```